# How to Use Custom Lock screen Password in android

Tags: android, lockscreen

In my application I would like to Custom Lock to some activities.
I had found the Android Lock Pattern Lib. [Lock Pattern Lib Link](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/)

But I didn't understand how to use this lib in my project repeatedly

I Would like to display Lock screen Like

[image]

Please help to develop this